# CakePHP replace app model with model from plugin

Tags: php, cakephp

I have model and entity in my CakePHP(latest) app that I want to extend in this way. I want to tell the cake to use **ExtraStuff** model class instead of app **Stuff**

```
App\Model\Table\Stuff

MyPlugin\Model\Table\ExtraStuff
```

I'm trying to redefine model in the main controller in beforeRender method with methods from **Cake\Datasource\ModelAwareTrait**

```
/**
 * Override a existing callable to generate repositories of a given type.
 *
 * @param string $type The name of the repository type the factory function is for.
 * @param callable $factory The factory function used to create instances.
 * @return void
 */
 modelFactory($type, callable $factory)
```

Or how I can do it? I have a lot of **$this->loadModel('Stuff')** calls inside the project and I need to tell the app use ExtraStuff class when I need.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Look this
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers.html#loading-additional-models

If you are using a table provider other than the built-in ORM you can link that table system into CakePHP’s controllers by connecting its factory method:

```
// In a controller method.
$this->modelFactory(
    'ElasticIndex',
    ['ElasticIndexes', 'factory']
);
```

After registering a table factory, you can use loadModel to load instances:

```
// In a controller method.
$this->loadModel('Locations', 'ElasticIndex');
```